# Driving MOSFET gate using PIC

Tags: mosfet, logic-level

I would like to drive a MOSFET gate using 12V (in order to reduce the drain-source resistance). Using the answer from a few post i've read I have come up with the following circuit. Will this circuit work for an application where i will be switching the motor on and off one every 10 minutes?

Further more is this the best method of driving the FET? and is there any type of "MOSFET driver IC" i can use to reduce space on my PCB?
[image]

Comment: You asked a somewhat similar question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/188096/mosfet-driving-mosfet-for-reduced-reduced-rds and one of the answers includes a schematic to drive your motor. The circuit you presented has a problem when PIC GPIO = 0

Comment: What current does the motor take?

Comment: motor will take up to 20A

Comment: Hi efox29, Yes this question is similar. However i have modified my question based on the answers I had received. The circuit presented in this question also is different to the one provided in the answers and hence i wanted to check that It would still work with the modifications i had made

Comment: Do you consider your previous question to be adequately answered? If so then please select the answer you think is best and mark it as "accepted"

Comment: Google "gate driver ic".

Comment: @user3095420  This sort of update is done by editing the original question, rather than posting a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following circuit. It cuts down on parts from the given schematic. This is probably as tight as it gets in terms of board space. R1, R2 can be as small as you care to solder.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBOX1A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Note that your circuit requires an active-low motor enable signal.

Comment: Good point @DaveTweed. Handle accordingly in the code.

Comment: Sorry, but I wouldn't use this circuit. The reason: when the PIC is not driving its output (for example, when it's being reset), this circuit will switch on the motor, which, IMHO, is not a safe design. To save a single trasistor and a resistor...

Comment: Where a known initial state is required, a pull-up should be used.

Comment: @HoustonFortney or pull down.